# Can I redraw my hand at the start of the game in Sentinels of the Multiverse?

Tags: sentinels-of-the-multiverse

I was playing as Expatriette in a Sentinels of the Multiverse game and my starting four cards were all ammo cards.  As each ammo card says it has to be played next to a gun card, I effectively couldn't do anything with my hand.

Do the official rules allow a hero to trash and redraw their starting hand?  If so, is there a penalty?  I searched the official rulebook and the Rook City expansion book and didn't see anything, but I don't know if one of the later expansions or official rulebook clarifications added a provision about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No, the rules do not allow for mulligans and the official site has no provisions in any expansion or clarifications that add this feature.**

The official sites [downloads page](http://sentinelsofthemultiverse.com/downloads) has copies of the official rules and the rules for each expansion. None mention a process for mulligans of your initial 4 card hands. The **Changes** section also only notes changes to the Villian, Heroes, and Environments cards and no changes to the turn structure.

From the [rule book](http://sentinelsofthemultiverse.com/system/files/downloads/Sentinels%20of%20the%20Multiverse%20Enhanced%20Edition%20Rulebook.pdf) (page 4)

> **Game Setup**
>
> [...] After the heroes, villain, and environment have been chosen, each player draws the top four cards of their hero deck. The game begins with the villains turn, then proceeds clockwise around the table [...]

Comment: I guess the "draw two cards if you didn't play a card or use a power" is meant to help in situations like this then.